# Getting Out of memory when reading large excel files (.xls) using Workbook method of apache poi jxl-2.6.jar

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, out-of-memory, hssfworkbook

1. File size is **10mb**.
2. File format is **.xls**
3. I am using the `Workbook` class from **jxl-2.6.jar** file of apache poi.

   ```
   try {           
       Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(filePath);//**after this line i am getting OOM**
        sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetcount); // this line is even not executing.            
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Please notice this is a **.xls** file, not a .xlsx file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try increasing the heap size and turning off GCC overhead with the command line flag -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit. Also, -XX:MaxPermSize value can also be increased. Please provide stack trace as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried all these options but OOM still persists.